# What happens if I didn't link my app from admob

Tags: android, admob

I uploaded my first app to Playstore, and I want to link to it from my admob account. I can't find it! It says: **No application found. Please refine your query.** Knowing that I can access it from Playstore, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As [Google Support has noted](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3034835?hl=en), it can take up to a week for your app to be findable by AdMob. Doesn't matter if it's already available in the Play Store.

If after a week it still doesn't show up you can contact the support.

Comment: So while it takes the 1 week for "Link Your App" to find the app, does it mean the impressions and clicks don't get counted and I don't get paid for that week even though App is live in App Store?

Comment: @HELLO good question. I'd say no but have never tested this. Would interesting to know.